# Installation of Websphere 8 in Windows

Tags: websphere

I am trying to install Websphere Application Server 8.5 in Windows 7 64 bits but I have had difficulties.
The server is Windows 7 64 bits and I am using the Installation Manager.

I tried to use both the 64 bits version (DEVELOPERSILAN.agent.installer.win32.win32.x86_64) and the 32 bits (DEVELOPERSILAN.agent.installer.win32.win32.x86) but I got the message:

> The package com.ibm.websphere.DEVELOPERSILAN.v85 specified in the install.xml file wasn't located. The same message for IBMJAVA.v70, liberty.IBMJAVA.v70, IHSILAN.V85, APPCLIENTEILAN.v85, PLGILAN.v85, PLUGCLIENTILAN.v85, WCTILAN.v85, W2MTKILAN.v11 and liberty.DEVELOPERSILAN.v85.

Should I install anything else before the Installation Manager?

Answer (score 1):

I recently downloaded WAS8.5 on Windows R2 2008. Hope I could answer your question.
Installer Manager 32-bit will work.
Did you add the repository with file name "repository.config" to the Installation Manager?
This should be same for any product when you install from Installation Manager. 
Make sure to provide Admin privileges to the IM when starting it.